# Write Velocity file forced in UTF-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, velocity

I'm using the following code to output a Velocity template to a file :

```
FileWriter fileWriterOut = new FileWriter(outFile);
logger.debug("encoding " + fileWriterOut.getEncoding());
fileWriterOut.write(template.getStringWriter().toString());
fileWriterOut.close();
```

Problem is :

Deployed in a non UTF-8 App Server, outFile is written using default encoding (iso-xxxx).

You can verify it with fileWriterOut.getEncoding()

It seems that no method in FileWriter class could set another encoding.

How can I force UTF-8 when writing my file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `FileOutputStream` in combination with an `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(...);
final Writer writer 
    = new OutputStreamWriter(out, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Seems quite the same solution anyway :)

Comment: @ObscurMoirage yup :) With Java 7 it's as easy as `Files.newBufferedWriter(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do this, I'm not sure that's the most convenient one, but it works correctly.

```
Writer out = null;
try {
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFile), "UTF-8"));
    out.write(template.getStringWriter().toString());
} 
catch ...
finally
{
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch...
}
```